# Operator + cant be applied to operands of type Quaternion and int

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, game-development

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, RotatePoint.transform.rotation + 90);
```

I'm trying to instantiate a shield at some object location but it spawns 90 degrees off, I just need it to turn that much.

But the code I'm using clearly isn't working. I need some help.

Comment: Think we need to know what `RotatePoint` is and what is returned by `RotatePoint.transform.rotation`.

Comment: RotatePoint is another game object and RotatePoint.transform.rotation is the reference to the transform of that game object, I want to instantiate the shield with the same rotation as "RotatePoint", but I need it to be 90 degrees more. @JohnWu

Comment: So if `RotatePoint.transform.rotation` is a reference, why are you trying to add an `int` to it?

Comment: Well the script that isnt working is for the shield itself, I want the shields rotation to be the same as the RotatePoint so im making it the same as the RotatePoints rotation, Im not really sure what im doing, kind of teaching myself c#

Comment: To make the rotation the same, use `transform.rotation = RotatePoint.transform.rotation;`.  The problem above is that you are trying to add an int to a Quaternion.  A Quaternion has 4 components, and does not have an overload for the `+` operator with respect to the integer type.

Comment: To add 90 degrees to a rotation, you need to multiple the rotation by another rotation that has the 90 degree rotation.  Something like.. `transform.rotation = RotatePoint.transform.rotation * Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 90);`

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to change the rotation angle of our object.

1. transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0,90,0));
   This method changes the rotation of the world coordinates, so when the script containing it is mounted under a child node of an object, and the rotation of the parent node is not (0,0,0,), there will be a bug.

The parent node is shown in the figure:

[image]

The child node is shown in the figure:

[image]

The child node rotates 90 around the Y axis, and the above code is also called, and the problem in the picture below will occur:

[image]

2. Transform.eulerAngles assignment.

   transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0,90,0);

   When you want to achieve child node rotation.

   transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0,90,0); (rotate relative to parent coordinates).

[image]